# Try-catch issue

Tags: vb.net

I am running across an issue in my program. I am reading a folder containing `csv` files and entering the data into a list of arrays. I have data enclosed within quotes.
However, the data is not pristine, and there are fields that have spare quotes that are causing issues.

I have set up a `try/catch` function that shunts the bad data into a manual verification routine. However, today the `try/catch` has **started clearing the stack and reprocessing all the files from the top of the folder**.

I have been using the messageboxes to trace exactly when the stack is getting cleared.  It's happening at the start of the try/catch statement.  It's not making it to the first `messagebox`.

Does anyone have any tips for continuing the program without losing the stack data?

```
files_ = Directory.GetFiles(path_, "*.ldf") 'picks out only the .ldf files

For i = 0 To files_.Length - 1 'i is the index for the number of ldf files in the folder.  Number is i+1
     i_string = CStr(i)  

     Using filereader1 As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(files_(i), System.Text.Encoding.Default)
         filereader1.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited
         filereader1.Delimiters = New String() {","}
         filereader1.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True

         While Not filereader1.EndOfData

            Try
               split_string = filereader1.ReadFields()
            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & " : " & FileName & " ; " & filereader1.ErrorLine & " LIST")
               error_throw = filereader1.ErrorLine
               MsgBox("LIST error throw")
               Throw_Error = True
            End Try
```

Comment: I would suspect that you're getting an exception not covered by the catch block.  Try eliminating the Try/Catch block and see what exception is thrown.

Comment: What do you mean by "stack is getting cleared"? Does filereader restart at first file in directory path? I'd add a check for a common `Exception` within try catch block.

Comment: Wouldn't the msgbox I put in there display the catch as it gets created?  Because I'm getting resets without any error message.

Comment: Franz, yes, I set a message to pop up whenever the function starts, and it restarts without throwing an error message.

Comment: We need to know what exception you are getting.  The MessageBox in the catch will only be triggered on a MalformedLineException, but not on any other exception.

Comment: I'm not getting any other exceptions.  The program runs, and occasionally clears the stack/starts over.